# Partition list of tuples based on a value within each tuple

Tags: python, list, sorting, if-statement, tuples

I am trying to sort a set of data in to 2 separate lists, fulltime and parttime. But it doesn't seem to be working. Can somebody point to where I'm getting this wrong?

```
data = [(['Andrew'], ['FullTime'], [38]), 
       (['Fred'], ['PartTime'], [24]), 
       (['Chris'], ['FullTime'], [38])]

def sort(var1, datadump):
    positionlist = []
    for b in range(0, len(datadump)):
        temp2 = datadump[b][1]
        if (temp2 == var1):
            positionlist.append(datadump[b])
    return (positionlist)

FullTimeList = sort("FullTime", data) 
PartTimeList = sort("PartTime", data)

print(FullTimeList) 
print(PartTimeList)
```

Comment: Use `if (temp2[0] == var1):`

Comment: More broadly, consider sticking a `print` statement just before your `if` statement to verify that the variables you're using contain the data that you think they do.

Comment: You have a list of tuples of one-element lists. Therefore `datadump[b][1]` gets a list. As suggested, printing the `temp2` would be the first step of debugging. Generally debugging through printing is a thing that helps a lot of newbies. ;)

Comment: Another thing would be to consider altering your data structure (if that is possible of course) to simply be strings instead of one-element lists...

Comment: Since you're a beginner, I would urge you to find more descriptive names for your variables...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is solved by altering

```
if (temp2 == var1):
```

to

```
if (temp2[0] == var1):
```

This is because the elements within each tuple are lists holding a string, not the strings themselves.

This problem could also be solved using two list comprehensions:

```
FullTimeList = [x for x in data if x[1][0] == 'FullTime']
PartTimeList = [x for x in data if x[1][0] == 'PartTime']
```

Comment: Or change the data to not use lists for the string fields.

Answer (score 3):

Not an answer: just a suggestion.  Learn how to use the python debugger.

```
python -m pdb <pythonscript.py>
```

In this case, set a breakpoint on line 9

```
b 9
```

Run the program

```
c
```

When it breaks, look at temp2

```
p temp2
```

It tells you

```
['FullTime']
```

Look at var1

```
p var1
```

It tells you

```
'FullTime'
```

And there is your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You'll get a better understanding if you name your variables and functions with descriptive names:

```
data = [(['Andrew'], ['FullTime'], [38]), 
        (['Fred'], ['PartTime'], [24]), 
        (['Chris'], ['FullTime'], [38])]

def filter_records(value, records):
    result = []

    for i in range(len(records)):  # i and j are usual variable names for indices (b is not)
        record = records[i]
        name, work, hours = record   # give names to the parts 
        if work[0] == value:         # work[0] since the values are lists (no need for parenthesis)
            result.append(record)
    return result                    # no need for parenthesis

FullTimeList = filter_records("FullTime", data) 
PartTimeList = filter_records("PartTime", data)
```

the pattern:

```
for i in range(len(records)):
    record = records[i]
```

is an anti-pattern in Python - meaning that there is a better way to write it:

```
for record in records:
    ...
```